# Sync local branch with remote branch

Tags: git, github

What I am trying to do is -

1. I change a file in my local dev server. I upload the file in remote server. I update the remote branch from remote server.
2. Then I check the git status of my local dev branch. It gives me

> git status
>
> On branch dev Your branch is behind 'origin/dev' by 3 commits, and can
>   be fast-forwarded.   (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
>
> Changes not staged for commit:   (use "git add ..." to update
>   what will be committed)   (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard
>   changes in working directory)
>
> ```
> modified:   models/event.js
> ```
>
> no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

When I try `git pull origin dev` then it asks me to commit or stash my changes first before merge.

How can automatically sync my local branch with remote same branch. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @GoodDeeds I have already did a push to remote branch from remote server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should check if file `models/event.js` was modified before. If it's true you can't apply pull from server, because changed data discourage it.

Run this:

```
git status
```

And see, if this file was changed. If it's true you may stash your changes first, then apply pull from server and after that pop your changes from the stash:

```
git stash

git pull origin dev

git stash pop
```

Or if `models/event.js` contained useless changes just revoke them first and run `git pull` command:

```
git checkout -- models/event.js

git pull origin dev
```

Comment: Thanks. It works now. I had to checkout and then pull.

Comment: BTW, if you have changes in few or more files and you want to discard them all use `git reset --hard` command. But be carefull, check your changes before doing this

Comment: Yes that's a good idea. What will be a good way to move changes from local machine to remote folder via git. Local changes to git and then pull in remote server?

Comment: If I understood a question correctly, a common way to change your remote repo data is done some changes locally in cloned repo, commit them, and push on remote server

Comment: Thank you. When you say "push on remote server" how do you do that?

Comment: It's easy enough. After you commit your changes locally 1) execute `git pull --rebase origin dev` command in order to receive last changes from server and 2) execute `git push origin dev`, where `dev` is a branch name. Last command send your local commits on server